# Horizontal button bar with slider in Vaadin

Tags: java, user-interface, slider, vaadin, vaadin-flow

My goal is to create a horizontal button bar with a variable number of buttons in it. Each button click should open a certain, new gui that is embedded into the extisting one, above the HorizontalLayout.
[image]

The first button should always be there. This is the code so far:

```
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout implements PageConfigurator
{
    int number = 10;

/**
 *
 */
public MainLayout()
{
    super();
    this.initUI();
    this.createButtons();
}

private void createButtons()
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= this.number; i++)
    {
        final Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Button" + i);
        button.setHeight("120px");
        button.setWidth("120px");

        this.horizontalLayout.addComponentAtIndex(i, button);
    }
}

@Override
public void configurePage(final InitialPageSettings settings)
{
    settings.addLink("shortcut icon", "frontend/images/favicon.ico");
    settings.addFavIcon("icon", "frontend/images/favicon256.png", "256x256");
}

/* WARNING: Do NOT edit!<br>The content of this method is always regenerated by the UI designer. */
// <generated-code name="initUI">
private void initUI()
{
    this.div              = new Div();
    this.horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    this.button           = new Button();

    this.button.setText("Button");

    this.button.setWidth("120px");
    this.button.setHeight("120px");
    this.horizontalLayout.add(this.button);
    this.div.setWidth("100px");
    this.div.setHeight("100px");
    this.horizontalLayout.setWidthFull();
    this.horizontalLayout.setHeight("100px");
    this.add(this.div, this.horizontalLayout);
    this.setSizeFull();
} // </generated-code>

// <generated-code name="variables">
private Button           button;
private HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout;
private Div              div;
// </generated-code>

}
```

My questions:

- How do i get a slider in my horizontal layout for the buttons? So that, when there are too many buttons, i can swtich the view.
- Later on i would like to update the button bar, so "number" will change at runtime. The button bar should recognize this change and create as many buttons as given. How do i implement the updating?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using the Tabs widget that comes with Vaadin, for switching between views. Is there more to your button bar than just switching content? Dynamically adding/dropping tabs is supported, as is a scroller for when you have more tabs than can fit on screen.

Comment: I am using Vaadin Flow

Answer (score 2):

> How do i get a slider in my horizontal layout for the buttons?

For this I recommend using the add-on [ScrollLayout](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/scrolllayout) which provides the two classes `VerticalScrollLayout` and `HorizontalScrollLayout`. You would use the horizontal one for this case. Use it like any other HorizontalLayout, but if there's not enough space to display all content, it will expand horizontally and add a horizontal scrollbar. I made this add-on myself so if there's any problem don't hesitate to ask. (There is no V14 version of this add-on but you can use the V13 version in your V14 project, it's compatible)

> Later on i would like to update the button bar, so "number" will change at runtime. The button bar should recognize this change and create as many buttons as given. How do i implement the updating?

1) Remove all existing buttons
2) Add the right amount of buttons again

```
private void updateButtons(){
    this.horizontalLayout.removeAll();
    createButtons();
}
```

Edit: This is the easy way of doing it, by removing ALL buttons then re-adding the right amount. If you want to be a little more fancy, you could try to keep some buttons if they're gonna be readded anyway. example: let's say you initially have 4 Buttons. When you change the `number` to 3, you would only have to remove the last Button, instead of removing 4 then adding 3. This would have the upside that any changes you may have done in the respective shown layouts of the buttons would not be discarded. This would be an important difference if you're using a `Binder` inside the shown/hidden layouts.

---

As a sidenote, you are basically implementing the functionality of `Tabs` with buttons here. While this is certainly possible, I would recommend you try it with Tabs. I know you tried it yesterday but I think you gave up too soon. I realize the Tabs are somewhat complicated, but you will have to create similar complexity using this button solution (the current implementation of yours is not finished yet - you still have to create a layout that shows for each button, and add a click listener that will trigger this visibility change)

Comment: Another reason I changed to buttons is because there are more possibilties to style them. Or am im wrong?

Comment: it definitely will have a different look / styling possibilities. Technically you could add a button in each tab. not sure how great that would look though. I'm not trying to push you into using Tabs, just know that it's not getting easier with Buttons.

Comment: As long as it is no dead end, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Tabs

You are replicating the functionality already built into the Vaadin [*Tabs*](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs/) and [*Tab*](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.9/com/vaadin/flow/component/tabs/Tab.html) widgets. No need to re-invent the wheel here. Furthermore, you will confuse your user by having buttons that act like tabs, merely switching between content panels within the window.

[image: Screenshot of "Tabs" widget in use with a scroll control or the right edge, along with its source code]

Tabs have the features you asked for:

- Switching content panels within window
- Scrolling if too many to fit on the screen
- Appearance can be customized via Vaadin [themes](https://vaadin.com/tutorials/themes-and-styling-in-vaadin) ([*Lumo*](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.5.0/demo/) & [*Material*](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-material-styles/1.2.3/demo/)) and CSS.
  (See examples at bottom of [this page](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs/java-examples).)
- Tabs can be added and removed. You can also disable a tab, to be faded yet still readable while inactive.

To switch content, merely hide or show by calling [`setVisible`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.9/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.html#setVisible-boolean-). Hiding via CSS is very fast. And `setVisible` to false also shuts off updates to the Vaadin component from the Vaadin server, so you can freshen the hidden content (if need be) without the cost of updating the browser unnecessarily.

The *Tabs with pages* section of that [examples page](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs/java-examples) gives you a nice code example for managing content switching. A `Map` tracks the relationship of each tab to its content. The listener method at the bottom switches content by hiding & showing. Copied here:

```
Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab one");
Div page1 = new Div();
page1.setText("Page#1");

Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab two");
Div page2 = new Div();
page2.setText("Page#2");
page2.setVisible(false);

Tab tab3 = new Tab("Tab three");
Div page3 = new Div();
page3.setText("Page#3");
page3.setVisible(false);

Map<Tab, Component> tabsToPages = new HashMap<>();
tabsToPages.put(tab1, page1);
tabsToPages.put(tab2, page2);
tabsToPages.put(tab3, page3);
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(tab1, tab2, tab3);
Div pages = new Div(page1, page2, page3);
Set<Component> pagesShown = Stream.of(page1)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
    pagesShown.forEach(page -> page.setVisible(false));
    pagesShown.clear();
    Component selectedPage = tabsToPages.get(tabs.getSelectedTab());
    selectedPage.setVisible(true);
    pagesShown.add(selectedPage);
});
```

## `PagedTabs` widget

As you can see from that code snippet above, the `Tabs` & `Tab` widgets bundled with Vaadin do not actually switch content. Those widgets are just the bare minimum for (a) displaying themselves on screen in a theme-compliant manner, and (b) knowing when they have been clicked.

Fortunately, Alejandro Duarte authored a widget wrapping `Tabs` & `Tab`. The [*paged-tabs*](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/paged-tabs) is described on the [*Vaadin Directory*](https://vaadin.com/directory/search). You can download, or install via Maven. The product is free-of-cost and open-source (Apache License 2).

With `PagedTabs`, you pass content while adding each tab. That content is automatically swapped when clicking between tabs. No need for you to track which content belongs to which tab. And no need for you to show/hide content. The widget includes methods for adding or removing tabs, removing the matching content as well. Indeed, this widget supports having a "Close" control to delete a tab.

[image: Screenshot of "paged-tabs" widget in use on a web page]

Unfortunately, I cannot get this `PagedTabs` widget to constrain itself to the width of the browser window. The scroll control never appears within the tab bar. Instead, the user must scroll the entire web page to the right to access the extra tabs. I filed [Issue # 11](https://github.com/alejandro-du/paged-tabs/issues/11).

This `PagedTabs` project is certainly a good idea and looks promising. Check it out, perhaps that problem will be fixed, or perhaps you can find a workaround.